# Codeigniter combine two results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have two queries. I have to execute both queries and return in same result object.
for example

```
$query1 = "SELECT name,age from students";
$query2 = "SELECT name,age from users";
$result1 = $this->db->query($query1)
$result2 = $this->db->query($query2)
 return result1 and result 2 together ;
```

I have to return the result of both queries in same object. please help me

the actual query is ::

```
SELECT dev_members.name,dev_members.id,dev_members.age,dev_members.family_id,dev_family.house_name,dev_ib_account_registration.account_id FROM (dev_members) 
JOIN dev_family ON dev_family.id=dev_members.family_id
JOIN dev_ib_account_registration ON dev_ib_account_registration.member_id=dev_members.id
           UNION
SELECT dev_members.name,dev_members.id,dev_members.age,dev_members.family_id, dev_family.house_name,dev_ib_sub_member_registration.account_id FROM (dev_members) 
JOIN dev_family ON dev_family.id=dev_members.family_id
JOIN dev_ib_sub_member_registration ON dev_ib_sub_member_registration.member_id=dev_members.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION`

```
$query = "SELECT name,age from students 
          UNION
          SELECT name,age from users";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

Or if you want to identify records from which table row belongs to then

```
$query = "SELECT name,age, 'students ' AS `table_type` from students 
          UNION
          SELECT name,age, 'users' AS `table_type` from users";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
```

Comment: I have given an example query, I'll add the actual query by editing the question

Comment: @user3387036 using union in query will result all the records from both tables in same object.what you additionally need update your question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You might want to search for a question before asking it..

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18532548/combining-results-from-2-databases-in-codeigniter) is the same question already with an answer.

Comment: Hm... Try echo '<pre>'; print_r($result1); print_r($result2); echo '</pre>';

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT name,age from students UNION ALL SELECT name,age from users";
```

You need to use UNION ALL instead of UNION in your query

```
SELECT dev_members.name,dev_members.id,dev_members.age,dev_members.family_id,dev_family.house_name,dev_ib_account_registration.account_id FROM (dev_members) 
JOIN dev_family ON dev_family.id=dev_members.family_id
JOIN dev_ib_account_registration ON dev_ib_account_registration.member_id=dev_members.id
           UNION ALL
SELECT dev_members.name,dev_members.id,dev_members.age,dev_members.family_id, dev_family.house_name,dev_ib_sub_member_registration.account_id FROM (dev_members) 
JOIN dev_family ON dev_family.id=dev_members.family_id
JOIN dev_ib_sub_member_registration ON dev_ib_sub_member_registration.member_id=dev_members.id
```

UNION removes repeating rows in final result set while UNION ALL keeps the duplicate.