# PhP (Codeigniter) Merging query results before foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, merge, querying

I would like know if it is possible to merge sql queries like the following from codeigniters active record.

```
   //get assigned contacts    
      $this->db->select('*, CONCAT(first_name, " " ,last_name) AS name', FALSE);
      $this->db->from('customers_contacts');
      $this->db->join('customers_accounts', 'customers_accounts.contact_id = customers_contacts.contact_id');
      $this->db->like('CONCAT(first_name, " " ,last_name)', $q);
      $results1 = $this->db->get();
    //get non assigned contacts
      $this->db->select('*, CONCAT(first_name, " " ,last_name) AS name', FALSE);
      $this->db->from('customers_contacts');
      $this->db->like('CONCAT(first_name, " " ,last_name)', $q);
      $results2 = $this->db->get();
```

I tried using `$query = array_merge($results1, $results2);` but that does not work, I believe because `->get()` is returning an array of objects.

So I got it to work by putting both through a foreach loop, and then merging the resulting arrays. But I need to do some conditionals that would be easier in one foreach loop than two.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, because both queries are on the same table, only one being joined with a junction table, (assigned vs unassigned contacts) there are extra columns being returned in the assigned contacts.  So union won't work.

Comment: I think you need this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4345554/convert-php-object-to-associative-array

Answer (score 2):

You can use like below

```
$arr_results1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
$arr_results2 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
var_dump(array_merge($arr_results1,$arr_results2));
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of reading I came up with the following and it works!

```
//first query here...
$results1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
//second query here...
$results1 = $this->db->get()->result_array();
//then...
$query = array_merge($results1,$results2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You must always do `$results->result();` to get an array of rows after `$results = $this->db->get();`. **note:** `$results->result();` is an array of objects.

For example

```
# ...
$results1 = $this->db->get();

# ...
$results2 = $this->db->get();

$results = array();

if ($results1->num_rows()) 
{
    $results = array_merge($results, $results1->result());
}

if ($results2->num_rows())
{
    $results = array_merge($results, $results2->result());
}

return $results;
```

This will return an array of objects (rows) and you iterate through data as usual:

```
foreach ($results as $row) 
{
    echo $row->id;
    echo $row->column_name_1;
    # and so on...
}
```